# How to prove this inequality given the equation

Tags: inequality

Given $ a>0 $ and $ a^5-a^3+a=3$, how can I prove the inequality: $ a^6 \ge 5 $ ?
I have tried factorizing the equation, solving for $ x, x^2, x^3 $ and then adding equations made together. Last but not least I tried, to solve for $x$ and then raise it to the power of $ x^6 $, but none of these seem to work

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $a^5 - a^3 + a = 3$, we can factorise the left hand side to write $a(a^4-a^2+1)=3$.

The second factor here is reminiscent of cyclotomic polynomials/finite geometric series - in any case, we can write it as $\frac{a^6+1}{a^2+1}$, and clear fractions to get to $a(a^6+1)=3(a^2+1)$.

Now, we spot the $a^6$ we're looking for on the left hand side, and rearrange to see that $a^6 = 3\frac{a^2+1}{a}-1=3(a+\frac{1}{a})-1$.

There are a number of ways of showing $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq2$ for $a>0$ - the easiest is probably differentiating with respect to $a$ to find a minimum at $a=1$, but you can equally use the arithmetic-geometric inequality or a number of other methods. Substituting $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq2$ back into the previous inequality gets us to $a^6\geq3(2)-1=5$ and we're done.

We also could have, upon spotting the $a^6$, subtracted 5 and looked for a reason for it to be positive - in this case, we'd see that $a^6 - 5 = 3(a+\frac{1}{a})-6=3(a+\frac{1}{a}-2)$, and pushing through this a bit takes us to $\frac{3(a^2-2a+1)}{a}=\frac{3(a-1)^2}{a}$.

It's then clear that $a^6=5+\frac{3(a-1)^2}{a}$, which displays fairly immediately that the inequality holds.

Comment: +1 for this. I would say the easiest way to show that $a+\frac{1}{a} \ge 2$ is the identity $a+\frac{1}{a} = (\sqrt a - \frac{1}{\sqrt a})^2 + 2$.

Comment: I'm a fan of this, though in this context, I favor the $\frac{(a-1)^2}{a}$ because it makes more explicit use of the $a>0$ constraint. Also manages to sidestep having to include a line justifying that you're allowed to take square roots.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $a^5-a^3+a=3$ is equivalent to $0=a^5-a^3+a-3 =: f(a)$

You can easily see that the derivative $f'(a) = 5a^4-3a^2+1$ is strictly positive everywhere (I leave the proof to you with the hint $b := a^2$.) which implies that there is just one real root of $f$, let us call it $a_0$

Observe that $f(25/19)<0$. That means the root $a_0>25/19$. Therefore $a_0^6 > \left(\frac{25}{19}\right)^6 >5$.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a simpler solution to my problem:

$$a^5 -a^3 + a = 3 $$
Multiply by $a$:
 
$$a^6 - a^4 + a^2 = 3a $$

$$a^6 = a^4 - a^2 + 3a \ge 5 $$
Multiply by $a$:
$$ a^5 - a^3 + 3a^2 \ge 5a$$

Changing the first equation: $$a^5 - a^3 = 3-a$$
Then: $$3-a + 3a^2 \ge 5a$$
$$3a^2 + 3 - 6a \ge 0$$
Divide by $3$: 
$$a^2 + 1 -2a \ge 0$$
$$(a-1)^2 \ge 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of $z^2-z+1$ is negative, hence $a(a^4-a^2+1)=3$ implies $a>0$.

Since $z^2-z+1$ attains its minimum at $z=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(z)=z^4-z^2+1$ attains its minimum, $\frac{3}{4}$, at $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Moreover, $0<f(z)\leq 1$ if $z\in[0,1]$, hence $z\cdot f(z)=3$ implies $z>1$.

$g(z)=z\cdot f(z)$ is an increasing function over $[1,+\infty)$ as the product of two positive increasing functions. Since $g(5^{1/6})<3$ by direct computation, in order to have $g(z)=3$

$$ z > 5^{1/6} $$
must hold. It may be useful to notice that:
$$ g(z) = \frac{z(z^6+1)}{z^2+1}, $$
hence if $z=5^{1/6}$ we have $g(z)=\frac{6z}{z^2+1}<3$ by the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score -1):

Define $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}: x \mapsto x^5-x^3+x-3$. Then $$
f^\prime(x)=5x^4-3x^2+1=5\left(x^2-\frac{3}{10}\right)^2+\left(1-\frac{9}{20}\right)>0.
$$
Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing, so it is sufficient to check that $f(5^{1/6})<0$.